# Unexpected = in coffeescript class definition

Tags: coffeescript

I'm new to coffee script, and there is likely more things wrong with this definition than this problem itself.

Given

```
class window.SlideManager                                                                                                                                                                     
  constructor: (@$contentDiv, @analyticsCanvas) ->                                                                                                                                            
    @iterator = Iterator(@slides)                                                                                                                                                             
    @slides = @$contentDiv.data('slides')                                                                                                                                                     

  nextSlide: ->                                                                                                                                                                               
    try {                                                                                                                                                                                     
      url = @iterator.next()                                                                                                                                                                  
    } catch {                                                                                                                                                                                 
      @iterator = Iterator(@slides)                                                                                                                                                           
      url = @iterator.next()                                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                                         

    this.renderSlide(url)                                                                                                                                                                     

  renderSlide: (slide) ->                                                                                                                                                                     
    $.get(slide, {nolayout: 'true'}, (data) ->                                                                                                                                                
      @$contentDiv.contents().replaceWith(data)                                                                                                                                               
      window.setupCanvas($(@analyticsCanvas), window.createChartData(window.getVisitCounts($(@analyticsCanvas))))                                                                             
    )
```

I get a unexpected = syntax error on line 8 (`url = @iterator.next()`)

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be using braces:

```
nextSlide: ->                                                                                                                                                                               
  try                                                                                                                                                                           
    url = @iterator.next()                                                                                                                                                                  
  catch
    @iterator = Iterator(@slides)                                                                                                                                                           
    url = @iterator.next()
```

> First, the basics: CoffeeScript uses significant whitespace to delimit blocks of code. You don't need to use semicolons `;` to terminate expressions, ending the line will do just as well (although semicolons can still be used to fit multiple expressions onto a single line). Instead of using curly braces  `{` `}` to surround blocks of code in functions, if-statements, switch, and [try/catch](http://coffeescript.org/#try), use indentation.

See: http://coffeescript.org/

Comment: To explain a bit further: Braces in CoffeeScript are used to denote object literals. So it things that `{ url = @iterator.next() }` is meant to be an object, which is obviously not the right syntax for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use this without `brackets{}`:

```
nextSlide: ->                                                                                                                                                                               
  try                                                                                                                                                                           
    url = @iterator.next()                                                                                                                                                                  
  catch
    @iterator = Iterator(@slides)                                                                                                                                                           
    url = @iterator.next()
```

instead of this:

```
nextSlide: ->                                                                                                                                                                               
    try {                                                                                                                                                                                     
      url = @iterator.next()                                                                                                                                                                  
    } catch {                                                                                                                                                                                 
      @iterator = Iterator(@slides)                                                                                                                                                           
      url = @iterator.next()
```